# Why to code a script which will check if some package is installed in linux and if not then install it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Let's assume I downloaded a bash script from github and then run it on my sys then after running it shows

checking xyz package {found]

checking abc package [not found]

installing abc ....

How do they do that?

Comment: Have you tried it, or had a look around? This was pretty easily found on google... https://askubuntu.com/questions/519/how-do-i-write-an-application-install-shell-script

Comment: View the script!

Answer (score 0):

Here the way i was able to check it:

```
## function to install missing packages - $1 : package name.
require_pkg() {

    if ! command -v $1 >/dev/null; then

        msg_warn missing_pkg $1
        echo "Do you want to install $1 ? (works only with apt-get package manager) [y/N]"
        read -r YESNO

        if [[ $YESNO =~ ^([yY][eE][sS]|[yY])$ ]]; then
            apt-get --force-yes --yes install $1
        fi

        echo "$1 will not be installed. This package is required so considere to install it ..."

    fi

}
```

As you can see, i've used `command -v`. But iirc there is like 3 or 4 methods to check if a package is installed! I've choosed this one because, iirc again, it was one of the most reliable in different linux OS.

For information, msg_warn is a function i've made in my script (not shown in this answer) to print a warning message "missing package".

Hope this way to operate your question will inspire you :).